# Customize Create funciton in DRF viewset

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, drf-queryset, django-viewsets

I want to customize the user viewset i.e. when the user registers the user account was created as well.

im doing this :

````py
class CustomUserCreate(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = RegisterUserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.save()
            if user:
                profile_serializer = ProfileShortSerializer(data = request.data)
                profile = profile_serializer.save()
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)```

is this the right approch?
````

Comment: What is not working with your attempt?

Comment: I was a little confused. Is it the right approach or not?